# UDP client not forming packets correctly

Tags: c++, linux, udp

I'm attempting to create a client in Linux to allow for the sending of UDP packets. So far, the program seems to form all of the parts correctly, but when I attempt to send data, the program fails to send the packet.

[I've put the code here](http://pastebin.com/aMLjWTUk), and the example output from the code is as follows:

```
jeremiah@ubuntu:~/Documents/Networking 2/Lab3/client$ sudo ./a.out 192.168.1.128 22222
great success
Imperial Soviet Comrade: SVN -> sin_family: 2
Imperial Soviet Comrade: SVN -> sin_port: 52822
Imperial Soviet Comrade: SVN -> sin_addr: -2147374912
Attention Comrade: Enter Message: red


Imperial Soviet Comrade: Data in packet dump ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: start
Imperial Soviet Comrade: the size of the UPC is 1576
Imperial Soviet Comrade: Socket: 3
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> flags: 1
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> offset: 0
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> length: 8
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> filename: red
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: UPC -> data: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Imperial Soviet Comrade: sizeof(UPC): 8
Imperial Soviet Comrade: sockaddr.sin_family: 2
Imperial Soviet Comrade: sockaddr.sin_port: 52822
Imperial Soviet Comrade: sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr: -2147374912
Imperial Soviet Comrade: sizeof(sockaddr): 8
Imperial Soviet Comrade: Data in packet dump ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: end


Imperial Soviet Comrade: size_sent: -1
Alert Comrade: Data not sent: Invalid argument
```

It fully compiles without error, but there are warnings from castings in the printf functions. Any help that can be given would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `sendto(SOCKET, UPC, sizeof(UPC)+2*MAX_MESSAGE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)` -- why send a 2803 byte datagram when you really want to send a 3-byte datagram? This wastes bandwidth, guarantees IP fragmentation on any "normal" link, and the kernel may just choose to throw such a packet away (which could be the reason it doesn't work). Also note that `select` in combination with `recvfrom` is kind of silly. You can instead just block in `recvfrom`, which is more efficient and the same effect (btw. you do only receive half as much as you send, too -- `recvfrom(SOCKET, buffer, MAX_MESSAGE, ...)`)

Answer (score 1):

This is really suspicious:

```
int size_sent = sendto(SOCKET, UPC, sizeof(UPC)+2*MAX_MESSAGE, 0, 
                       (struct sockaddr*) &TARGET, sizeof(TARGET)+2*MAX_MESSAGE);
```

Why are you adding 2 * MAX_MESSAGE to both the message length and the size of your sockaddr struct?
The last is quite probably the reason your `sendto()` call is returning -1.

Also keep in mind that sizeof(UPC) is going to be 4 or 8, not what you want it to be.

Comment: I honestly had those in there as I was unsure if it was sending the size that I needed. I did remove both of those, and I've gotten the exact same response.

Comment: That's because sizeof(TARGET) is wrong too. TARGET is a pointer, not the structure it's pointing to. Note that that makes &TARGET wrong too. You want sendto(..., TARGET, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); instead.

Comment: You are missing a very, very fundamental C/C++ concept -- the size of something has nothing to do with what it contains, only with its type. If you perform a `sizeof` operation on a pointer, you get the size *of* *that* *pointer*.